# How to add several XML-schemes with same namespace to WSDL?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to create WSDL that should check (via SOAP) several xml which have same namespaces.
For example I have these xml:

```
<ns3:person>
  <ns3:name>Steve</ns3:name>
  <ns3:address>US</ns3:address>
</ns3:person>
```

and

```
<ns3:person>
  <ns3:name>Steve</ns3:name>
  <ns3:height>160</ns3:height>
</ns3:person>
```

I wrote xml-schemes for them, but i can't add their xsd-files to WSDL (import/include to `<wsdl:types>`) because they have same namespace.

Thanks.